# Ruby ERB not reflecting changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to change an ERB to remove the line

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

However, the resulting `div` tag still appears on the page, even 30 minutes after the fixed file was uploaded to the server. The server is running Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.1.2, and the affected files (`two_column.html.erb` and `three_column.html.erb`) were downloaded from (and uploaded to) `app/views/layouts/`. There doesn't appear to be anyone else who has experienced this problem, and I'm at a loss as to the cause.

**Installed Gems**

```
actionmailer
actionpack
actionwebservice
activerecord
activeresource
activesupport
acts_as_ferret
ar-extensions
capistrano
cgi_multipart_eof_fix
daemons
dsl_accessor
fastercsv
fastthread
ferret
gem_plugin
god
highline
hoe
hpricot
mislav-will_paginate
mongrel
mongrel_cluster
mysql
needle
net-sftp
net-ssh
passenger
rails
railsmachine
rake
rmagick
rubyforge
rubygems-update
rubyist-aasm
sources
tzinfo
```

Comment: Have you rebooted your server? You might be seeing a cached verison of the page.

Comment: Rails will cache whatever you tell it to cache, but I always assume that a server reboot is required whenever I make changes unless I am using WEBBrick.

Comment: Will try that after backing up latest application release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen browsers do some fairly weird caching in the past ... this probably seems obvious, but have you flushed your browser cache?  As an alternative you could try just getting the page with cURL or Wget and see if it contains your changes.

Comment: The ERB file reflects the change when accessed via FTP or Vim, but the putatively-removed <div> still appears when the page is loaded by any computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and `service httpd restart` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is named file.html.erb

Also, upgrade to Rails 2.3.x it's much faster!

Good luck,

Kent

Comment: Checked, and that wasn't it, unfortunately. And I'll consider upgrading if I can be sure it won't break anything.

Comment: As a sanity check. open up IRB and go

require 'rubygems'
require 'erb'

If either of those return false, you've found your problem.  Could be a problem with the path.